# Is there a way to retrieve gatling session variables(independent to each user Eg:5 users) use those variables in karate feature

Tags: scala, karate

Using Karate 1.3.1
Gatling plugin 4.2.9
I tried to retrieve the multiple gating session variables defined in the .scala file logic looks like this

```
val TestScenario = scenario("MultipleUser")
    .exec { session =>
      session.setAll(Map(
          "randomNumber" -> generateRandomNumber(),
          "randomUUID" -> generateRandomUUID()))}
    .exec { session =>
      if (session.contains("randomNumber")) {
        println("myVariable exists")
        println("randomNumber: " + session("randomNumber").as[Long])
        println("randomUUID: " + session("randomUUID").as[String])
      } else {
        println("myVariable does not exist")
      }
      session
    }
    .exec(karateFeature("classpath:com/test/karate-gatling/features/test.feature"))

  setUp(
    TestScenario.inject(atOnceUsers(5))
```

My question is will I get new values of `randomNumber` and `randomUUID` for each virtual user in the above construct?  When I tried to get the value in `test.feature` with `karate.get("randomNumber")` function to pass the value to the path of URL. got an `null` value.

In the println `randomNumber` and `randomUUID` the data is the same for all 5 users. I was expecting to be different.

Could you please help me with this? Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the concept of `karateSet()` explained in the docs. https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-gatling#chaining

Comment: thanks @PeterThomas, the link had provided gave me another idea to fix my problem. It works as well!

Comment: @ram that is good to hear. do see if you can post a snippet as an answer or suggest an addition to the docs to help others